Web Scraping with 2 Dropdowns of .aspx Form
I'm trying to scrape this form in R - https://profiles.doe.mass.edu/statereport/enrollmentbygrade.aspx. The form has two dropdowns, 'Report Type' and 'Year'. I've been using this response as a guide.
I basically want to scrape each year's data for schools, but can't quite sort it.
Any help would be appreciated...
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

# Start session, extract years 
url <- read_html("https://profiles.doe.mass.edu/statereport/enrollmentbygrade.aspx")
form <- html_form(url)[[2]]
years <- form$fields[[5]]$options

# Update form with years, submit, and extract type.
form <- html_form_set(form, 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddYear' = years[1])
url<- html_form_submit(session, form, "<unnamed>") #This doesn't seem to work 
form <- html_form(url)[[2]]
type<- form$fields[[4]]$options[2]type 

And it seems to fall apart here -
# Update form with type, submit, and extract data frame(s).
form <- html_form_set(form, 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddYear' = type[1])
url <- html_form_submit(url, form, "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hfExport")

df_list <- html_table(url, T, T, T)


To use rvest sessions, you should replace calls to rvest::read_html() & rvest::html_form_submit() with rvest::session() & rvest::session_submit()
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

# helpers
header <- \(s) html_elements(s, "h1#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hTitle") |> html_text(trim = TRUE)
rprt_table <- \(s) html_element(s, "table#tblAccountability") |> html_table()

# Start session, extract years & report types
s <- session("https://profiles.doe.mass.edu/statereport/enrollmentbygrade.aspx")
(years <- html_form(s)[[2]]$fields[["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddYear"]]$options)
#> 2023-24 2022-23 2021-22 2020-21 2019-20 2018-19 2017-18 2016-17 2015-16 2014-15 
#>  "2024"  "2023"  "2022"  "2021"  "2020"  "2019"  "2018"  "2017"  "2016"  "2015" 
# ...

(report_types <- html_form(s)[[2]]$fields[["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddReportType"]]$options)
#>        District          School   Collaborative 
#>      "DISTRICT"        "SCHOOL" "COLLABORATIVE"

# limiting request rate to 1 per second
slow_session_submit <- slowly(session_submit, rate = rate_delay(1))

# allocate a list for reports, named, filled with NULLs
report_lst <- map(years,\(y) NULL)
head(report_lst, n = 3) |> dput()
#> list(`2023-24` = NULL, `2022-23` = NULL, `2021-22` = NULL)

# collect reports for 4 years
for(i in seq_along(years[1:4])){
  message(str_glue("collecting {(years[[i]])} ... "), appendLF = FALSE)
  # populate form from the last session as hidden form values that 
  # carry ASP session state might change, though in this specific case those seem
  # to remain constant throughout the session  
  form <- html_form_set(html_form(s)[[2]], 
                        "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddYear"       = years[[i]], 
                        "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddReportType" = report_types["School"])
  s <- slow_session_submit(s, form)
  report_lst[[i]] <- rprt_table(s)
  message(header(s))
}
#> collecting 2024 ... 2023-24 Enrollment by Grade Report (School)
#> collecting 2023 ... 2022-23 Enrollment by Grade Report (School)
#> collecting 2022 ... 2021-22 Enrollment by Grade Report (School)
#> collecting 2021 ... 2020-21 Enrollment by Grade Report (School)

# bind into a single frame
report_lst |>
  list_rbind(names_to = "year")

Resulting frame / tibble :
#> # A tibble: 7,344 × 19
#>    year    `School Name` `School Code` PK    K     `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`  
#>    <chr>   <chr>                 <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#>  1 2023-24 Abby Kelley …       4450105 0     121   119   123   128   123   124  
#>  2 2023-24 Abington - A…         10001 78    0     0     0     0     0     0    
#>  3 2023-24 Abington - A…         10505 0     0     0     0     0     0     0    
#>  4 2023-24 Abington - A…         10405 0     0     0     0     0     0     170  
#>  5 2023-24 Abington - B…         10020 0     177   161   168   0     0     0    
#>  6 2023-24 Abington - W…         10015 0     0     0     0     192   160   0    
#>  7 2023-24 Academy Of t…       4120530 0     0     0     0     0     0     30   
#>  8 2023-24 Acton-Boxbor…       6000505 0     0     0     0     0     0     0    
#>  9 2023-24 Acton-Boxbor…       6000005 0     56    67    63    76    61    90   
#> 10 2023-24 Acton-Boxbor…       6000020 0     60    61    63    58    67    50   
#> # ℹ 7,334 more rows
#> # ℹ 9 more variables: `6` <chr>, `7` <chr>, `8` <chr>, `9` <chr>, `10` <chr>,
#> #   `11` <chr>, `12` <chr>, SP <chr>, Total <chr>

Created on 2024-05-03 with reprex v2.1.0

Thanks! The only additional question I have is how might I turn this pull into a dataframe?

Edited to include an example of how you may collect frames to a list and then bind those together.

Another option with rvest and httr.
### Packages
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

### Download the start page
b=read_html("https://profiles.doe.mass.edu/statereport/enrollmentbygrade.aspx")

### Get and generate the list of Years
y=b %>%
  html_elements(xpath = '//select[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddYear"]/option') %>%
  html_text2() %>% 
  str_extract("\\d{4}") %>%
  as.numeric()+1

### Get the parameters for the requests
VS=b %>% html_element(xpath = '//input[@id="__VIEWSTATE"]') %>% html_attr("value")
VSG=b %>% html_element(xpath = '//input[@id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"]') %>% html_attr("value")
EV=b %>% html_element(xpath = '//input[@id="__EVENTVALIDATION"]') %>% html_attr("value")

### Write a function to download and transform the data
babar=function(x){
    out=POST(url = "https://profiles.doe.mass.edu/statereport/enrollmentbygrade.aspx",
           body = list("__VIEWSTATE"=VS,
                       "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"=VSG,
                       "__EVENTVALIDATION"=EV,
                       "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddReportType"="SCHOOL",
                       "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddYear"=x,
                       "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hfExport"="ViewReport")
  )
  df=content(out) %>%
    html_element(xpath = "//table") %>% 
    html_table %>% 
    mutate(year=x,.before=1,
           `School Code`=str_pad(`School Code`,8,side = "left",pad = "0"),
           across(everything(),~as.character(.x))) %>% 
    filter(`School Code`!="00000000")
  if (nrow(df)==0) {df[1,1]<-as.character(x)}
  return(df)
}

### Apply the function
out=map(y,babar,.progress = TRUE)

### Merge the results and format the data
output=bind_rows(out) %>% 
  mutate(year=paste0(as.numeric(year)-1,"-",year),
         `School Name`=str_squish(`School Name`),
         across(4:19,~as.numeric(str_replace(.x,",",""))))

Output :
# A tibble: 57,538 × 19
   year      `School Name`             `School Code`    PK     K   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`   `7`   `8`   `9`  `10`  `11`  `12`    SP Total
   <chr>     <chr>                     <chr>         <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2023-2024 Abby Kelley Foster Chart… 04450105          0   121   119   123   128   123   124   126   115   104    90    83    78    87     0  1421
 2 2023-2024 Abington - Abington Earl… 00010001         78     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    78
 3 2023-2024 Abington - Abington High  00010505          0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   143   135   129   146     8   561
 4 2023-2024 Abington - Abington Midd… 00010405          0     0     0     0     0     0   170   162   165   139     0     0     0     0     0   636
 5 2023-2024 Abington - Beaver Brook … 00010020          0   177   161   168     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   506
 6 2023-2024 Abington - Woodsdale Ele… 00010015          0     0     0     0   192   160     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   352
 7 2023-2024 Academy Of the Pacific R… 04120530          0     0     0     0     0     0    30    55    62    64    60    56    52    61     0   440
 8 2023-2024 Acton-Boxborough - Acton… 06000505          0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   403   425   403   415     3  1649
 9 2023-2024 Acton-Boxborough - Blanc… 06000005          0    56    67    63    76    61    90    94     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   507
10 2023-2024 Acton-Boxborough - C.T. … 06000020          0    60    61    63    58    67    50    48     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   407
# ℹ 57,528 more rows

Notes :

A "year" column has been added to the results.
"State Totals - State Totals" have been removed from each table. You can compute them afterward.
The "School Codes" are complete with the presence of leading zeros.
Colums 4 to 19 are set to numeric. Thousands separators have been removed.
Year 1993 is present in the output even if no data is displayed on the website.
We could have downloaded .xlsx  for each year with the same method but .html is fine for this case.
A third alternative could have been to use chromote to interact with the page and get the data.

